# How to concatenate two dependent variables inside a map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to concatenate 2 variables inside a map function, but I can't get it working. One depend of the other. I need to get the sequence of objects e.g. drink.strIngredient1, drink.strIngredient2, drink.strIngredient3... and so on.

```
const currentIndex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

{ ingredientIndex.map((currentIndex) => (
   `${drink.strIngredient + currentIndex}`
))}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: how does the drink and ingredientIndex look like

Comment: One correction. The first argument in the map function is the value it self and the second one is the index. Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @SangamRajpara it's correct, i'm getting from another array, that's a condition of my application.

Comment: `${drink.strIngredient}${currentIndex}`?

Comment: You're looking for bracket notation to access the property names.  For example: `drink['strIngredient' + currentIndex]`

Comment: @David thanks for your solution, it worked! drink['strIngredient${currentIndex}'`] . Please answer the question than I chose as correct answer, thank you.